# Install a Package from another Distribution

Tags: apt, package-management, system-installation, software-installation

I installed Ubuntu under Windows 10 using the Ubuntu App from the Windows store.

The lsb_release -a command gives:

[image]

I installed two genetics programs:

```
sudo apt install bwa
sudo apt install samtools
```

and successfully ran them.

When I went to install a third program, minimap2, I got the message:

[image]

I searched the Ubuntu Packages library, and it is there, but under the disco and eoan distributions, and not the bionic distribution.

[image]

How can I either:

1. Download the minimap2 package from disco or eoan from within my bionic distribution of Ubuntu, or
2. Replace the bionic distribution of Ubuntu on my Windows 10 machine with the disco distribution?

Comment: Most likely the package from newer releases won't install.

Comment: @Pilot6 - Ah! Didn't realize those were newer releases. Then I have to upgrade to Ubuntu 19.04 (Disco) or 19.10 (Eoan). Hopefully it is available on Windows.

Comment: Releases use alphabetical naming: Bionic (18.04), Cosmic (18.10), Disco (19.04), Eoan (19.10), etc. Use only packages for your release - others may or may not work...or may break your system.

Comment: As a Windows user installing Ubuntu for the first time, I assumed that the version 18.04 available last week by Microsoft in their store would have been the latest version of Ubuntu, so it was my false impression that there were just different libraries of packages, not that there were later versions of Ubuntu. None-the-less, posting here helped me find the answer I needed.

Comment: @user535733 - alphabetical naming of packages is cool.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like I need to upgrade to Ubuntu 19.04 (Disco) or Ubuntu 19.10 (Eoan).

I found instruction on how to upgrade my Windows 10 installation at:

[How to Upgrade Ubuntu 18.04 to 19.10 on Windows 10 Linux subsystem](https://www.how2shout.com/how-to/how-to-upgrade-ubuntu-18-04-to-19-10-on-windows-10-linux-subsystem.html)
by Sarbasish Basu, Oct 19, 2019

That worked and I was successfully able to install and run minimap2 from the disco distribution.

Comment: you can also try to install it manually following the instructions at its github page: https://github.com/lh3/minimap2

Comment: Thanks @AlexOnLinux, but I wonder if those instructions will need modifications for Ubuntu running under Windows 10.

Comment: Oh sorry my fault. Didnt read properly.